# JQuery - Change background-image of a span based on numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to change the background-image of a span which has a numeric value printed by PHP. As I can see in FireBug, the code is working but the image isn't loading and I'm almost sure that the path is the correct one. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function () {
    var score = parseInt($('#score').text().trim());
    var color = 'red';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
        if (score >= 40) {
            color = 'orange';
        }
        if (score >= 60) {
            backgroundimage = 'url(images/+.png)';
        }
        $('#score').css('background-image', backgroundimage);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="nota-puntuacion">
   <span id="score">
     85 <!--Value Printed by PHP-->
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this:

```js
$(function () {
  changeSpanScore = function (score) {
    bg = {};
    if (score > 0)
      if (score < 25) {
        bg.color = "#f00";
        bg.image = "images/img-1.png";
      } else if (score < 50) {
        bg.color = "#0f0";
        bg.image = "images/img-2.png";
      } else if (score < 75) {
        bg.color = "#00f";
        bg.image = "images/img-3.png";
      } else {
        bg.color = "#fff";
        bg.image = "images/img-4.png";
      }
    else {
      bg.color = "";
      bg.image = "";
    }
    $("#score").html(score).css({
      "background-color": bg.color,
      "background-image": bg.image
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p>Enter number and press Enter.</p>
<input type="text" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) changeSpanScore(this.value);" />
<br /<br /><br />
<div class="nota-puntuacion">
  <span id="score">
    85 <!--Value Printed by PHP-->
  </span>
</div>
```

In your case, if you are using reserved words in your images, you need to URL Encode them, so change the code to:

```
backgroundimage = 'url(images/%2b.png)';
```

Comment: I tried that and I tried to change the image and still can't get it working. The code you provide me allows to change the background color but what I want is to change the background image. Thank you for the help anyway :)

Comment: @Neks Yeah, you can do it using the same code. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Neks I have updated the answer. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't know what am I doing wrong, I'm just new in this, but background-image still not working. I'm using this for a Wordpress review system and I can get it to change the text color of the span but not the image :(

Comment: Try to use an absolute URL for the image like `color.image = "/path/to/the/image.png";`.

Comment: @Neks Would you mind accepting my answer if it works?

Comment: Wow, that worked. Using an absolute path for the image got it working. I don't like that way that much but well, it's something.

Comment: @Neks Even I am against it, but considering Wordpress, you have to use that $h!t!!!

Answer (score 0):

A plus sign in an URL is interpreted as a space. You would URL encode it into `%2b`:

```
backgroundimage = 'url(images/%2b.png)';
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried to change to a different image and nothing, the image isn't loading :(